# Azure: az acr build --no-push image is not present on local host

Tags: azure, docker, command-line-interface

Using `az acr build --no-push` correctly builds the image, it reports the info like the image was created in remote registry, but the image is not pulled to the local machine.

Is it possible to fetch the built image?

If not, the switch should be called `--dry-run`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when Azure Container Registry builds the image, it needs an agent to run the build command. So the parameter `--no-push` means ACR builds the image in that agent, but does not push it to the ACR. The only thing you get from this build command is the process to build the image and you will know if there are errors when you build the image. That's all.

Comment: So in that case it should really be called --dry-run shouldn't it?

Comment: @dosmanak Maybe yes. But I think it's more like a debug to check the issues before pushing.

Comment: So I created an issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/18412 perhaps some documentation improvement will suffice. Thank you.